# Using Regex in SOLR Query

Tags: regex, solr

I have a data set of street names and numbers which I need to search.

```
eg. 12 HILL STREET
    12A HILL STREET
    12B HILL STREET
    123 HILL STREET
    12 HILARY STREET
```

If I search as follows q=(street_name:12\ HILL*), I get

```
12 HILL STREET
```

I want to obtain the following results:

```
12 HILL STREET
12A HILL STREET
12B HILL STREET
```

Is there a way to query in SOLR to return the results as the above example shows?

I have tried querying as:

```
q=(street_name:/12[A-Z]\ HILL*/)
```

but don't get anything back.

Comment: Try `q=(street_name:/12[A-Z]* HILL.*/)`

Comment: (and the reason is that regexes in Lucene queries are _always_ anchored, so they have to match the whole token; the query at least have to end with `.*` as shown by Wiktor.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
q=(street_name:/12[A-Z]* HILL.*/)
```

Here, the pattern means

- `12` - string starts with `12`
- `[A-Z]*` - zero or more ASCII uppercase letters
- - a space
- `HILL` -  `HILL` char sequence
- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible (so, the rest of the line).

Comment: That resolves the confusion. I'd just change "the rest of the line" to "the rest of the token" - a Lucene regex matches against a stored token in the index, it's not line oriented as most traditional regexes (they're used for finding matching tokens in the index, not for matching against a blob of text as you'd usually do).

Comment: @MatsLindh `.` matches anything but line break chars, so `.*` means literally "any chars till line break". Which is "till line end" for me. What is passed to the regex engine  already depends on programming environment.

Comment: I know, I just want to make it clear to anyone that have indexed content as a single token that has linebreaks that it won't mean "to the end of the line" in Solr and Lucenes regex interpretation; it means to the end of the token as far as I know. All regexes are evaluated against the complete token, and does not do anything special regarding line breaks, etc. IIRC.